# Why do people say ReLU vs MaxPool order does not change the result?

Tags: neural-network

Upon Googling "Maxpool ReLU order" or similar, I've found many people saying this order does not effect the result, i.e.:

```
MaxPool(Relu(x)) = Relu(MaxPool(x))
```

Here are a small number of examples of people saying this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543428/activation-function-after-pooling-layer-or-convolutional-layer
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3180
https://www.quora.com/In-most-papers-I-read-the-CNN-order-is-convolution-relu-max-pooling-So-can-I-change-the-order-to-become-convolution-max-pooling-relu
https://towardsdatascience.com/convolution-neural-networks-a-beginners-guide-implementing-a-mnist-hand-written-digit-8aa60330d022

To be clear, I'm completely aware that there could be a slight speed difference, but what I'm asking about here is the computation result, not the speed.

For example, consider the following:
[image]

How can the general consensus be that the ReLU/MaxPool order does not effect the computation result when it's easy to come up with a quick example where is does appear to effect the computation result?

For what it's worth, ChatGPT seems to go against the general consensus:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. ChatGPT often speaks bullshit. Do not rely on it.
2. Your example is wrong. On the second computation, you are computing the absolute value, not ReLU: ReLU(-5) = 0 and ReLU(-3) = 0. The result is 2, which is the same as the first computation.
3. $\max(ReLU(x_1,...,x_n)) = ReLU(\max(x_1,...,x_n))$

Comment: good eyes on that `abs()`